# SQL Server 2008 Trigger: comparing data by input key

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

I am studying SQL Server 2008  Trigger and I got question about using inserted data to compare data inside in the table.

For example,

lets say we have table "testTb1"

inside of table

```
|id|section_id|current_num_student|max_num_student|
|1 |1         | 23                | 23            |
|2 |3         | 21                | 29            |
|3 |5         | 50                | 50            |
```

current_num_student is the number of student in the class  and max_num_student is maximum in the class. max_num_student will be defined by teacher, so it could be any numbers.

now a student wants to add the section 5 , however current_num_student is equal to max_num_student. Therefore, we have to reject a student.

query is like..

```
update testTb1  SET current_num_student = current_num_student + 1 WHERE section_id = ?
```

"?" will be input data by user in jsp.

therefore, i was trying to make trigger such as...

```
CREATE TRIGGER testTrg
on dbo.testTb1
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
IF EXISTS(select section_id FROM inserted i join dbo.testTb1 m on i.section_id = m.section_id
            AND m.num_cur = m.num_max)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('Can not update data because class is full', 16,1);
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; 
        RETURN
    END
```

something like that

however , i am getting error like..

I am not really sure the way to fix the problem..

Comment: What's the error you are getting? Seems like you forgot to post it...

Comment: Msg 8197, Level 16, State 4, Procedure testTrg, Line 1
The object 'dbo.testTb1' does not exist or is invalid for this operation.
i am getting this error :(

Comment: Are you sure that `testTb1` is really the name of the table? Are you sure it was created in the `dbo` schema? Are you sure you are trying to create the trigger in the right database? Are you sure you want to create the trigger without the `dbo` prefix?

Comment: testTb(ONE) or testTB(El)? Make sure you typed it right. Also, make sure you have the right connection under Server Explorer and make sure your schema is in fact dbo. Both common problems.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the join. How about this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER testTrg
on dbo.testTb1
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
IF EXISTS(select 1 FROM inserted i where i.num_cur = m.num_max)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('Can not update data because class is full', 16,1);
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; 
        RETURN
    END
```

Comment: I have a question then how can we referencing m.num_max ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be doing your rollback outside of this trigger.  I may be wrong but I think SQL server will want a Begin Transaction statement in the same scope.

Mike